# Use jquery drop-down menu to interact with each other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have an array with five numbers in it

```
  <scipt>
    var array = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
  </script>

  <form>
    <select id="num1">
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

When I click the button, a new drop-down menu is generated

```
<form>
  <select id="num2">
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Because I have selected 1 value above, the value of 1 has been removed when the second drop-down menu is generated.

```
<form>
  <select id="num1">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

At this time, because id = num1 selects 2 value, so when I change num2 num1, the value will also be changed.

I want to use the front-end to achieve this function, use JQUERY, how do you achieve this?

value will be given through the array.

Comment: You must first define correctly array like this: `var array = ["1","2","3","4","5"]`

Comment: ok~thanks.I change~

Comment: what do you mean by "At this time, because id = num1 selects 2 value"

Comment: When my second drop-down menu changes the value to 3, my first drop-down menu value does not appear 3

Comment: Can you show us your current Javascript / jQuery code?

Comment: Still thinking how to write

Comment: Something like this? https://jsbin.com/woberew/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Similar but the first one chooses 3 and the second 3 will disappear immediately

Comment: The second choice 2
 The first one to open cannot have 2